# Is there a rule for "kinks" in boundaries of point sets?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

Consider sets $A$, $B$, $C$ each being a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a set $D := (A \cap B) \cup C$. For the [given examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYZUt.jpg) the following obervation can be made: each of those marked red points $p_{R}:=\partial A \cap \partial B$ is has "kink" in  $\partial D$ (the boundary of D) iff $p_{R} \in C$. Analogous observatsions can be made for the green and blue points.

Is this a coincidence, or is there there a theory behind this?

Comment: In both of your example pictures you have shaded parts of $C$ that lie in neither $A$ nor $B$, so you have not shaded $D=(A\cup B)\cap C$.  If you correct the diagram, does your question still exist?

Comment: Sorry, that was a quirks in the notation. Definition of $D$ should now match to the shaded area.

Comment: Part of this is the sets chosen to illustrate this. What if the sets share a tangent where they intersect? Then there would be no kinks at all. If you want a more rigorous treatment of how sets intersect, in such a way that you do get "kinks", or higher dimensional equivalents, look up "Transversality of sets".

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look up *Gauss Codes*:

---

[image]

          

<sup>Image by Jeff Erickson: [PDF download](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/topology17/notes/02-planar-curves.pdf).</sup>

---